# How to remove and add items to an array?

Tags: java

In the positions of the array I keep objects, which is an employee and each employee has ID, first and last name.

I must delete an employee but without using any library and without using ArrayList.

The problem is, when removing an employee the array would look like this:

```
E E E E null E E E
```

E being an employee and nulling the deleted object, but when deleting I need the array to look like this:

```
E E E E E E E null
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You could do this as two steps, first set Array[4] to null, then loop through the Array bubbling the `null` object to the end.

Comment: If you'd prefer answers in Spanish you can ask at https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: No, it's a task, but I don't understand how to remove and add,
today they explained it only with ArrayList since the ArrayList has its own methods, but in this case it is with common 1 dimenson arrays

Comment: If this is homework for school, you should say so up front.

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited to using "plain arrays" then there are 2 obvious options:

1. A sort method that handles nulls and puts them at the end of the
   collection
2. Manually move all the items above the one you just removed down by one.

Comment: EN: Your answer gives me an idea, could you make a simple code? please
ES: Tu repuesta me da una idea, podrias hacer un codigo simple? por favor

Comment: Ok, thank you too, the idea helps me a lot :),
sorry for my regular English

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution that moves the value being removed to the end of the array, then sets that value to null.

```
// Remove an employee from the array at the given index
private static String[] removeEmployee(String[] employees, int index) {
    for (int i = index; i < employees.length - 1; i++)
        employees[i] = employees[i + 1];
    employees[employees.length - 1] = null;
    return employees;
}
```

Comment: I do not think that you need to swap as you know that the value is `null` - you just need to replace array[i] with array[i+1]

Comment: You're right. I edited my solution so that the null value is swapped with the last value, since OP asked to move the null to the end of the array.

Comment: No, you still need a loop to move all values down, then set the last item to null

Comment: Not sure I follow. Isn't that what the first version of my answer was doing? "set Array[4] to null, then loop through the Array bubbling the null object to the end."

Comment: If you change removing index 4, then index 4 is replaced with index5, index5 is replaced with index6 etc etc, then the last index is set to null.  Originally you were swapping 4 & 5, then swapping 5 & 6 etc etc.

Comment: Consider the 2nd item you delete - the array might be `E E x E E null` where `x` is the index to delete. Just swapping with the end of the array is not what you want to do - the result would be `E E null E E null`

Comment: @Scary Wombat Got it. Thank you for the assistance & the patience.

Comment: @John3136 Yes, that is something I had failed to account for. Thank you for pointing that out.